# Powershell get current script directory name only

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to store the current folder name into a variable (just the folder name, not the full path).

Everything that I could find on the internet is somehting like this:

```
PS C:\temp> get-location

Path
----
C:\temp
```

But what I want is just "temp" stored in a variable. How could I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7) to get the folder name from `Get-Location`with `-Leaf`:

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Location

Path
----
C:\temp

PS C:\temp> Split-Path -Path (Get-Location) -Leaf
temp
```

We can also use the automatic variable [`$PWD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#pwd) to get the current directory:

```
PS C:\temp> Split-Path -Path $pwd -Leaf
temp
```

Or using the automatic variable [`$PSScriptRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#psscriptroot), which uses the current directory the script is being run in:

```
Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Leaf
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7#parameters) for `-Leaf`:

> Indicates that this cmdlet returns only the last item or container in the path. For example, in the path C:\Test\Logs\Pass1.log, it returns only Pass1.log.

Additionally, as [@Scepticalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520315/powershell-get-current-script-directory-name-only/61520348#comment108825729_61520348) mentioned in the comments, we can use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7) and select the `BaseName` with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) from a specific folder(instead of just the current working directory):

```
PS C:\> Get-Item -Path c:\temp | Select-Object -Property BaseName

BaseName
--------
temp
```

Or just select the `BaseName` property directly with [Member Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/)(PowerShell v3+):

```
PS C:\> (Get-Item -Path C:\temp).BaseName
temp
```

Comment: Also be sure you need Get-Location. You can also use Get-Item -Path c:\temp | Select BaseName if you need the specific folder name instead of the current working directory name

Comment: @Scepticalist Good point. To just get the basename we can use `(Get-Item -Path C:\temp).BaseName`

Comment: And to get the folder name of the current script directory as the title asks for, you can use `Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Leaf`

Comment: (pwd).Path also works.

Comment: fyi: $PSScriptRoot does not change when you change the directory. So when using the $PSScriptRoot in the customizable prompt, it does not get updated when changing the directory